# Need to understand why console log returns an empty string instead of undefined

Tags: javascript

I need to console log first character of a word or if there is no word return undefined. Can someone give me a hint for my code please.

```js
const firstLetter = (str) => {
  // Your code here
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str[i] == str[0]) {
      return str[0];
    }
    const empty = undefined;
    if (str[i] == "" || empty) {
      return undefined;
    }
  }
  return str;
};

console.log(firstLetter(""));
```

Comment: If the string has no characters, the body of the loop is never entered because `i < str.length` is never fulfilled - so you progress straight to the `return str;` at the end - which, in such a case, is the empty string. `if (str[i] == str[0]) { return str[0];` doesn't make sense because that'll always be fulfilled if any iterations are performed. `|| empty` doesn't make sense either, `undefined` in an `if` condition will never fulfill it

Comment: You do not compare a variable to two constants with `variable == constant1 || constant2`. You use either `variable == constant1 || variable == constant2` or `[constant1, constant2].includes(variable)`. But the problem you're having is simpler; `str.length` is 0, so it never enters the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the for-loop wont run with your input of "", so the final `return` statement simply returns `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass **str** argument as an empty **""** string instead put something into it. The loop doesn't execute because it fails at `i < str.length` inside you for loop.